# InflateException: Error inflating class ImageView for VectorDrawableCompat

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

`VectorDrawableCompat` finally made its way into support library in SDK 23. But it doesn't seem to work, or maybe I'm missing something.

`drawable/mypic.xml`:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:height="64dp"
android:width="64dp"
android:viewportHeight="600"
android:viewportWidth="600" >
<group
    android:name="rotationGroup"
    android:pivotX="300.0"
    android:pivotY="300.0"
    android:rotation="45.0" >
    <path
        android:name="v"
        android:fillColor="#000000"
        android:pathData="M300,70 l 0,-70 70,70 0,0 -70,70z" />
</group>
</vector>
```

`fragment_bla.xml`:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/mypic"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

</FrameLayout>
```

This code works in Lollipop, but not in KitKat. What am I missing?

---

Exception:

```
09-06 14:26:53.637  31820-31820/com.bla E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.bla, PID: 31560
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:623)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:672)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400)
        at com.hohero.fragment.Intro1Fragment.onCreateView(Intro1Fragment.java:14)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
```

Comment: is there a `caused by` line after whatever you have posted in the logcat?

Comment: are you sure it comes to the support library? I cannot find it in the changelog of support library

Comment: @Bhargav nope, the rest is just low-level Android stuff

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html , maybe I have really missed it, can you point me to the line about that?

Comment: @DerekFung not sure why it's not mentioned, like they don't want people to use it :D I knew about it from http://stackoverflow.com/a/29943417/193550 but the best way to see it yourself is by downloading 23.0.1 from SDK Manager, then Ctrl+N for `VectorDrawableCompat` in Android Studio :)

Comment: Nah man... since half a year i have heard this rumor going around.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/vectordrawable/

It IS there... usage.. i dont know myself. Maybe you have to reference the appcompat xml tag `<android.support.v4.graphics.vector ...`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I believe the problem is 
`android:src="@drawable/mypic"` in your imageView setup.

Change that to
`app:srcCompat="@drawable/mypic"`

Then you should be good to go.

More details, please refer to: 
https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88#.mvuq06x1k

Comment: Daaaaamn!! =DDD I love stackoverflow! :D

Answer (score 2):

Well, I read the code and got it kind of working.  There are a couple of caveats:

1. The xml file must be in the raw directory, not drawable
2. The xml must be very simple.  It looks like it supports a single <path> element

For me it always has a red background and scaling doesn't seem to work right.  I just used the Vector Asset Action -> (lock) from the Studio Collection.

```
    final Drawable drawable = VectorDrawableCompat.createFromResource(getResources(), R.raw.ic_lock_outline_24dp);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

It's a good start and something to fun to play with!

Link to Google source in an unknown branch:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/d573775216408a88e796cd74abf8ab018488c2a3/v7/vectordrawable/src/android/support/v7/graphics/drawable